# Difficult agg in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i need to to transform a dataframe:

```
Seq((1, 1), (2,1),(3,2),(4,2), (5,1), (5,3), (6,3)).toDF("id", "compare_id") 

+---+----------+
|id |compare_id|
+---+----------+
|1  |1         |
|2  |1         |
|3  |2         |
|4  |2         |
|5  |1         |
|5  |3         |
|6  |3         |
+---+----------+
```

So that you get a dataframe like this:

```
Seq((1, 1, List(1,2,5,6), List(1,3)), (2,1, List(1,2,5,6), List(1,3)),(3,2, List(3,4), List(2)),(4,2, List(3,4), List(2)), (5,1, List(1,2,5,6), List(1,3)), (5,3, List(1,2,5,6), List(1,3)), (6,3, List(1,2,5,6), List(1,3))).toDF("id", "compare_id", "all_dependes", "all_compare_id")

+---+----------+------------+--------------+
|id |compare_id|all_dependes|all_compare_id|
+---+----------+------------+--------------+
|1  |1         |[1, 2, 5, 6]|[1, 3]        |
|2  |1         |[1, 2, 5, 6]|[1, 3]        |
|3  |2         |[3, 4]      |[2]           |
|4  |2         |[3, 4]      |[2]           |
|5  |1         |[1, 2, 5, 6]|[1, 3]        |
|5  |3         |[1, 2, 5, 6]|[1, 3]        |
|6  |3         |[1, 2, 5, 6]|[1, 3]        |
+---+----------+------------+--------------+
```

That is, in the third column I need to count all the ids connected to each other through some compare_id.
In the fourth, respectively, all the options for compare_id that id from the previous array has in the third column.

Basically I need a graph. But I don’t understand how to do this optimally in Scala/Spark.

Comment: Have a look at [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html)

Comment: However, if you'd prefer to continue using dataframes (not RDDs) then [graphframes](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/index.html) would be a better option.